# Visualize funnels in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have documents having following format:

{
Session ID, Previous URL, Current URL
}

I want to create visualisation for following scenario:

- How many users hit on URL B after hitting URL A and having same session ID?
- How many users hit URL A and URL B before hitting URL C and having same session ID?

To achieve this I need to compare documents within the same index.

I would like to know how I can do such type of queries in Kibana and create visualisation for this?